# (Groovy) Finding all Confluence spaces with a certain user group in it

Tags: groovy, confluence

as the title states, I want to be able to iterate through my Confluence System and find all spaces, in which a certain user group is in.
I am able to find a user group in a single space with the code below, but I can not seem to find an answer how to do this with ALL spaces.

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.SpaceManager
import com.atlassian.sal.api.component.ComponentLocator
import com.atlassian.confluence.security.SpacePermissionManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.security.SpacePermission
import com.atlassian.user.GroupManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.core.ContentPermissionManager
import com.atlassian.confluence.internal.security.SpacePermissionContext

def spaceManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpaceManager)
def spacePermissionManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(SpacePermissionManager)
def groupManager = ComponentLocator.getComponent(GroupManager)

def targetSpace = spaceManager.getSpace("NameOfSpace")
def targetGroup = groupManager.getGroup("UserGroup")

if (spacePermissionManager.getGroupsWithPermissions(targetSpace).contains(targetGroup)) { 
    //do something (in my case, remove User Group)
    
}
```

I tried it with "def allSpaces = spaceManager.getAllSpaces()" and substituted it into the getGroupsWithPermissions() method with no success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `SpacePermissionManager#getAllPermissionsForGroup`? I haven't tested this with Groovy, but at least in [Java](https://docs.atlassian.com/ConfluenceServer/javadoc/7.0.2/com/atlassian/confluence/security/SpacePermissionManager.html#getAllPermissionsForGroup-java.lang.String-), it returns a list of the space permissions attached with the user group.

Not all `SpacePermissions` will be attached to actual spaces so you will most likely need to loop through the list and filter results where `getSpace()` is not null.